# Why my view is not updated after page is destroyed and i come back with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

i have two pages

**APP COMPONENT HTML**

```
<a routerLink="hello-page">HELLO PAGE</a>
<div></div>
<a routerLink="counter">COUNTER</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**COUNTER HTML**

```
<p>{{ counter }}</p>
<button (click)="onBtnClick()">Click</button>
```

**COUNTER TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.css'],
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  counter: number = 0;
  onBtnClick() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
      console.log('interval counter', this.counter);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

**HELLO-PAGE HTML**

```
<p>
hello-page works!
</p>
```

when I visit the counter page and when I click on the button - I am starting interval - inside i am increasing the value of my `counter property` on every one second so `1 2 3 4 etc`.
Also the view is updated - we can see that `1 2 3 4` in the HTML.

While the interval is counting - I click on `HELLO-PAGE` link and I am routed to hello page component.
When I go on that page, I can see that the interval is still counting ( I did not cleared the interval when I destroyed the page in ngOnDestroy ) and he is still ticking.

After that when I go back on `counter` component again, the interval is still working and the counter is increasing BUT `THE VIEW IS NOT UPDATED`. `{{ counter }}` in the HTML is now 0.

I guess it is because the previos view is destroyed and now I have the new view.
I need to find a way where when I go back on that page I will get the value from the previous setInterval in my HTML.

So my HTML will be updated.

The full code you can find here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upmaek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcounter%2Fcounter.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcounter%2Fcounter.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fcounter%2Fcounter.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello-page%2Fhello-page.component.html

Comment: Use global shared service across all components, Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nugxtb?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

you can stop interval.

CounterComponent.ts:

```
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    clearInterval(this.intervalCount);/////
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  counter: number = 0;
  intervalCount: any;
  onBtnClick() {
    this.intervalCount = setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
      console.log('interval counter', this.counter);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to stop my interval. I need to procceed.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the interval into a service and in the `CounterComponent` inject the service and get the current counter value from it.